# How does R deal with tiny decimals? Converting .csv file list to numbers

Tags: r, csv

I've seen a number of threads about similar problems and have tried all the suggestions with no luck so far - I think maybe the issue is the size of the numbers in my file.

I have a .csv file with 5399 rows and one column of numbers with six decimal places and only three or four significant figures (eg 0.000615).

I can import the file without any problems and de-select the string to factor option, resulting in mode:list.

I have tried as.numeric(), as.character(as.numeric()), tried copying the data into a data frame, into a matrix, into a vector... nothing works. I can do simple maths on the list but cannot run the functions and loops I need to.

Because as.character(as.numeric()) normally works, I figure it must be an issue with the size of the numbers. Does R have a problem with tiny decimals?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are taking about. Please provide a clear example.

Comment: Sorry. I was asking how to convert my file from a list to numbers. I have found the solution: reading in the .csv file with the command read.csv2, which reads the list in as numbers.